# System.IO.IOException: Sharing violation on path in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, filestream, ioexception

I have used below code to save the file in xamarin forms ios but give me

> System.IO.IOException: Sharing violation

please help me.

```
FileStream fileStream = File.Open(pdfPath, FileMode.Create);
stream.Position = 0;
stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
fileStream.Flush();
fileStream.Close();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313303/file-sharing-violation-occurs-after-creation-of-file

Comment: P.S. It's unclear what the purpose of the `stream` is here, or the `fileStream`. You don't appear to actually use them for anything. Later, you simply write a completely different variable (`bArray`) to the file. In your code sample there is no indication of where this comes from.

Comment: P.P.S which line is throwing the exception? The first, or the last? Or another one? You didn't make clear. When reporting errors, always indicate precisely where the error occurs. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? I tried you code and did not get any error. And what is the `stream` in your code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked that your app has permission for accessing files on the system? Also i would to a check to see if the files exist before opening it with `File.Exists();`.

Also there are better ways of reading and writing to files in C#:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
string filename = Path.Combine(path, "myfile.txt");

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filename, true))
{
    streamWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow);
}

using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(filename))
{
    string content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(content);
}
```

Comment: how to give permission in ios , I am new in ios

Comment: Its in the info.plist file, you can read more about it here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system

Comment: I add permission in info.plist but not getting success

Answer (score 0):

You can try disposing the file stream before writing to a file.

```
FileStream fileStream = File.Open(pdfPath, FileMode.Create);
stream.Position = 0;
stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
fileStream.Flush();
fileStream.Close();
fileStream.Dispose();
File.WriteAllBytes(pdfPath, bArray);
```

Comment: but I face error in the first line of code "FileStream fileStream = File.Open(pdfPath, FileMode.Create);"